# Running loaded ant task from gradle multiple times with different properties

Tags: gradle, ant, checkstyle

We have an old ant build system that is still somewhat necessary to carry over. As we migrate functionality to gradle, we're still calling some of the more useful ant targets within gradle. One such useful ant target is a report summary appender which updates an index file with any reports that have been generated.

I'm adding checkstyle to our gradle build and attempting to call this target for each report that checkstyle generates. This report target requires some properties to be set, and those properties are unique for each checkstyle task (main vs. test). However, I can't seem to figure out how to invoke that ant target from gradle multiple times, but with different properties as ant properties seem to be global for the whole build.

What I've got so far:

```
ant.importBuild('build.xml') { antTargetName ->
    'ant-' + antTargetName
}

checkstyleMain {
  doLast {
    ant.properties['report.prop1'] = 'foo'
    ant.properties['report.prop2'] = 'bar'
    ant.properties['report.prop3'] = 'war'
  }
}
checkstyleMain.finalizedBy 'ant-report-summary'

checkstyleTest {
  doLast {
    ant.properties['report.prop1'] = 'aaa'
    ant.properties['report.prop2'] = 'bbb'
    ant.properties['report.prop3'] = 'ccc'
  }
}
checkstyleTest.finalizedBy 'ant-report-summary'

check.dependsOn checkstyleMain, checkstyleTest
```

This doesn't work when I run `check` because `ant-report-summary` is only executed once (gradle figures it doesn't need to run the same thing 3 times), so only uses the properties of the last run checkstyle task:

```
> Task :checkstyleMain
...
> Task :checkstyleTest
> Task :ant-report-summary
```

I want `ant-report-summary` to run once for each checkstyle task, with the properties specified in the `doLast`. Is this possible with clever task structuring or some other way?

Comment: Which versions of Ant and Gradle are you using? This will be helpful for experimentation.

Comment: Ant is 1.9.x and Gradle is 6.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/main/egg_StackOverflow_74378859)

I wasn't able to get it to work with `AntBuilder` (many braincells died) so my approach out-sources the properties to the Ant side. Consider the following command-lines:

```
ant report-summary -propertyfile main.properties
ant report-summary -propertyfile test.properties
```

where `main.properties` and `test.properties` are as expected. Then, if we use `Exec` tasks, things are a bit simpler.

A base-class task for calling Ant (**note:** edited for refactoring):

```
abstract class AntReportSummaryTask extends Exec {
    AntReportSummaryTask() {
        standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

        ext.output = {
            return standardOutput.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

and specific tasks with appropriate command-line (The following works for Unix, but can be easily changed to Windows) :

```
tasks.register('antReportSummaryMain', AntReportSummaryTask) {
    commandLine 'ant', 'report-summary', '-propertyfile', 'main.properties'
    doLast {
        println "TRACER antReportSummaryMain output:"
        println ext.output()
    }
}

tasks.register('antReportSummaryTest', AntReportSummaryTask) {
    commandLine 'ant', 'report-summary', '-propertyfile', 'test.properties'
    doLast {
        println "TRACER antReportSummaryTest output:"
        println ext.output()
    }
}
```

then:

```
checkstyleMain.finalizedBy antReportSummaryMain
checkstyleTest.finalizedBy antReportSummaryTest
```

and in my working example, `./gradlew clean check` will call Ant twice.

Comment: Using an `Exec` worked, though I structured it a little bit differently and added handling for potential Windows users (adding `'cmd', '/c'` to the `commandLine` arguments based on the OS). Thanks for the idea!